# Upload a CAD file into ArcGIS Portal as a hosted layer

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-portal, cad, spatial-etl

ArcGIS Portal has the ability [upload a shapefile](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/shapefiles.htm) and have this become a hosted layer.

Is there any pathway to upload a CAD file and have this become a hosted layer?

CAD is a [supported data type](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/supported-items.htm) for the `> Content > New Item` pathway, but the uploaded CAD file only has the option to "Download", and I can't see an option to (eg) use this data in a web map.

The below approach suggests itself, but I don't have the means to test it currently so I'm hoping someone can validate the thinking:

- write a tool using the [CAD to Geodatabase tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/cad-to-geodatabase.htm) in ArcGIS Pro
- publish this tool as a geoprocessing service
- expose an endpoint to upload a CAD file from the web
- perform the CAD -> geodatabase conversion in ArcGIS Portal
- load the resulting featureclass into ArcGIS Portal as a feature layer

Assuming there is no out-of-the-box tool, would the geoprocessing approach work?

Comment: You'll want to see this topic to see what source items can be turned into a hosted layer (CAD is not one): https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/use/publish-features.htm -- you're on the right approach investigating the construction of some sort of helper tool.